# Document viewer annotation behaving weirdly

Tags: 18.04, pdf, document

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have found this weird bug in the default document viewer. When I click on text annotation, the annotation is completely offset. To open the annotation, I still have to click the required text, but the yellow highlight appears about five lines underneath the text.

I have attached a photo, where the problem is visible clearly. This happens in several pdfs that I have. What can I do?

[image: The text selection(orange) and the annotation(yellow)]